# Image requests get 404, by browser gets 200

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I everybody! I have a **WordPress** enviroment running over **Apache Web Server**.

I've noticed that every **image requested within the HTML** SRC attribute, **gets 404** error code. But, the **same image** using the same URI **requested by browser navbar returns 200**. The main difference between them is where the initiatior is located:

**Requested initiated by src image attribute:**

```
GET /wp-content/gallery/media/Reuniones_Berg_2-300x225.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: www.transparencia.sasipa.cl
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
DNT: 1
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Referer: https://www.transparencia.sasipa.cl/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-UY,es-CL;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6,de-DE;q=0.5,de;q=0.4,es-419;q=0.3
Cookie: ...
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 25 Oct 2021 21:43:40 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Link: <https://www.transparencia.sasipa.cl/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Image **requested by copy-paste on browser** navigation bar:

```
GET /wp-content/gallery/media/1380344777.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: www.transparencia.sasipa.cl
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-UY,es-CL;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6,de-DE;q=0.5,de;q=0.4,es-419;q=0.3
Cookie: ...
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 15 Nov 2018 15:03:12 GMT
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 25 Oct 2021 21:35:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Nov 2018 15:03:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

No error_log file is generated by PHP.
Here is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 200M
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 200M
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I think it is a misconfiguration when referred or a CORS policy but I can't find anything.

Comment: I'm client side, and I don't know if it's my page's fault or the server's fault.